# Remove chapter number from bibliography in memoir

Tags: bibliographies, numbering

For my PhD thesis, I'm using [`memoir`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/memoir) class. I have some chapters, each one ending with a bibliography. I wish, both in the chapter and in the table of contents, the references title were not numbered. Can I do that?

**EDIT**: As rightly suggested by @Werner, I provide an example.

This is my main .tex file.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,italian,12pt,openright]{memoir}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\aliaspagestyle{part}{empty}
\usepackage[font=small]{quoting}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\definecolor{citations}{rgb}{0,.5,.5} % color for in text citations
\usepackage{doi}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
   colorlinks,breaklinks,
   linkcolor = {black},
   urlcolor = {blue},
   anchorcolor = {blue},
   citecolor = {citations}}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{rotating} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{url}
%\usepackage[singlespacing]{setspace} 
%\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,right=3cm,left=3.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[font=footnotesize,labelfont=bf,labelsep=space]{caption} 
\DeclareCaptionFormat{myformat}{#1#2#3\hrulefill}
\captionsetup[figure]{format=myformat}

\usepackage{textcomp} 
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}

\pagestyle{ruled}

\raggedbottom


\settocdepth{subsection}
\setsecnumdepth{subsection}

\renewcommand*\rmdefault{ppl} 

\graphicspath{{Figures/}}

\title{Title}
\date{}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}
    \chapterstyle{veelo}
    \frontmatter
    \begin{KeepFromToc}
        \tableofcontents
    \end{KeepFromToc}
    \mainmatter
    \cftaddtitleline{toc}{part}{Introduzione teorica}{}
    \part*{Introduzione teorica}
        \include{Chapters/Chapter1}
        \include{Chapters/Chapter2}
        \include{Chapters/Chapter3}
    \cftaddtitleline{toc}{part}{Lavori di ricerca}{}
    \part*{Lavori di ricerca}
        \include{Chapters/Chapter4}
        \include{Chapters/Chapter5}
    \cftaddtitleline{toc}{part}{Conclusioni generali}{}
    \part*{Conclusioni generali}
        \include{Chapters/Conclusions}
    \backmatter
    \cftaddtitleline{toc}{part}{Appendice}{}
    \chapter*{Appendice}
    \listoffigures
    \listoftables
\end{document}
```

Each chapter file end with:

```
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{D:/Documents/library}
```

This produce a ToC like this:

> 1 **Chapter title**
>
> 1.1 Section name
>
> 1.2 Section name
>
> ...
>
> 1.6 Bibliography

I want that it appears like this:

> 1 **Chapter title**
>
> 1.1 Section name
>
> 1.2 Section name
>
> ...
>
> Bibliography

Moreover, I also want that the bibliography title is not numbered inside each chapter.

Comment: From the documentation (Sec. 17): *The declaration `\bibintoc` will cause the `thebibliography` environment to add the title to the ToC, while the declaration `\nobibintoc` ensures that the title is not added to the
ToC. The default is `\bibintoc`*.

Comment: But I want that the bibliography appears in ToC, I'm only trying to make it not numbered, both in the main chapter and in the ToC. For example, `References` rather that `3.4 References`.

Comment: Ah, so you need to insert it in `toc` using `\begin{thebibliography}[1]\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}`. I guess that the default is an unnumbered chapter used to its header.

Comment: It would be (and always is) super-awesome if you could provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that the community can play with. One should be able to copy-and-paste-and-compile and have no problem for it to be considered a MWE.

Comment: @Werner I edited my question in order to make more clearness.

Comment: Sorry, but we don't have the files you `\include`. Please, make just one "pseudochapter" with one section (and minimal text) and an example of your chapter bibliography.